# How can I show an image with userAgent in Safari only?

Tags: javascript, safari, webgl, user-agent

I have some WebGL images on this website, but they don't work in Safari so I figured I'd display simple images in Safari only. I’m using userAgent, but I think I’m missing something. Also I’m getting this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘display’ of undefined
```

Any help or hint is much appreciated!

```
const editorImg = document.querySelectorAll('.editor-img');
        if(/Safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
            editorImg.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            editorImg.style.display = "none"; 
            console.log('hidden');
        }
```

This is my staging link: https://5c98ad-2bd965dd7504daa4ac960eec46ab6863.webflow.io/

Answer (score 0):

When using `querySelectorAll` you get an array of matching elements, which is why `editorImg.style` is equal to undefined in the error.

In order to get the style of those elements you can either :

1 -  Loop through the array of elements

```
editorImg.forEach(el => {
   el.style.display = block;
})
```

2 -  use `querySelector` instead, assuming there is only one matching element to `.editorimg`